# A proper way of defining methods strongly connected to the interface

Tags: c#

I have a following interface:

```
interface IName
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

And some base class BaseClass. Childs of this class may implement IName interface, but not all of them do.

If a Child implements IName, I would also like to override ToString() method, exactly the same way for all cases, as follows:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Name;
}
```

It seems that a good place for overriding ToString() would be in IName interface, but i believe that it is not possible in C#.
Implementing ToString() in every class seems a bad idea too, because it's a lot of code redundancy (and a waste of time).

What is a proper solution for a case like this?

Comment: add a base implementation such as an abstract class.

Comment: is there a reason you need this in the first place instead of calling `.Name`?

Comment: There is a base class (as I stated above), but I do not want to overide ToString() there, because it would affect child classes that do not implement IName.

Comment: Yes, there is. For the sake of discussion please assume, that there is a reason.

Comment: it would help to know why. just trying to root out an x-y problem.

Comment: It would maybe help to resolve my specific problem, but I would also like to know the general answer.

Comment: @wpfnoop please see that my proposed answer below is what you were seeking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to make a second base class as such:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    // your base class implementation
}

public abstract class NamedBaseClass : BaseClass, IName
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

this way, if you want a child to implement both BaseClass and IName, then you should inherit from NamedBaseClass.
According to your words that "some might implement IName and some not", then BaseClass should not implement IName, but you should still have some sort of a base implementation. this is my solution.

EDIT:

to make a single class which returns the name and has nothing to do with BaseClass, then you can make an unrelated abstract implementation just for that:

```
public abstract class NameStringClass : IName
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public override string ToString()
     {
          return Name;
     }
}
```

Comment: You should probably make the `ToString` override sealed.

Comment: you're probably right, I've never had to seal a method before so that didn't come to my mind at all. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This seems lika an OK approach, but what if I would like to implament IName in more than one base classes (which do not share any common ancestor other than object)? 
I would have to make such implementation for all of them...

Comment: See the edit for my suggestion :) once you've got NameStringClass for all the implementations, just inherit from it.

Comment: what you're asking is for a single class to implement logic from 2 abstract classes... that's not possible in C# (inheriting from 2 classes).
To ask for a specific logic to run for several classes which inherit from a single class is to ask for an abstract implementation... so I can't seem to find away around code duplication here, or at least refactoring it somehow to allow the code to exist in a single location somehow...

Answer (score 1):

Consider cFoo as the child class which has IName. And cBar parent class, and cBaz as a class which doesnt implement IName.

```
public interface IName
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class CBaz : CBar
{

}

public class CFoo : CBar, IName 
{
    public CFoo(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}

abstract public class CBar 
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this is IName)
        {
            var temp = (IName) (this);
            return temp.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

[Old Answer]
Note that an interface is essentially empty. You need to think of an interface as bearing more of the meaning of contract, implying that the person whom implements this interface as requiring to implement a property/method/field/etc of such signature.

For implementation specific tasks which may be shared commonly by many classes, an abstract class is more suitable.

The moment you need to resolve some kind of logic, you must go through a gateway of implementation, some implementation must occur, interfaces are essentially empty templates. The most loose way of implementing this is via an abstract class which contains both the name property and the ToString override, from which you then inherit from for all your subsequent classes.

At the same time you can consider an abstract class for your CBar class. As well as calling the base method base.ToString().
[End of Old Answer]

Comment: You're not returning the name here... am I missing something or have your forgot something in your code?

Comment: Your base class already implements the name. So cFoo will also have this property. It is a type of polymorphism thing

Comment: you're calling base.ToString(), since you only inherit for the interface IName, this will call the normal ToString() and therefore you've solved nothing here...

Comment: Yes but isnt the point such that the person can override it if they implement that interface? calling base method is only a suggestion.

Comment: but you'll still have to override it and write the implementation in every single class, that's what the OP was trying to avoid. so you still have to override ToString in each inheriting class... but again, am I missing something?

Comment: This is the same approach as in MichaelThePotato answer, I believe.

Comment: Why would you need to override it in every single class? see CFoo, it is just like that. anybody else that inherits it can use ToString off the bat

Comment: @wpfnoop that is why, the answer that you are looking for is to use abstract class directly. forget about the IName. All your classes that you intended to inherit IName interface should instead inherit directly from CBar abstract class instead. That is the only way you can get something to inherit a common functionality

Comment: the problem is, as I've stated in a comment to my response, that inheriting from the CBar class, prevents inheriting from other abstract classes which DO NOT implement CBar (like the BaseClass class OP mentioned in his question). hence, your answer doesn't fit. besides, I assume in CBar's ToString you mean to return the Name, so why not rewrite it?

Comment: @MichaelThePotato I am not rewriting the name because thats not what my intention, my intention is to provide a means of a proxy, to intercept the ToString() Method to maybe process it before going into the actual method call. I do not want to change the original functionality of ToString(). doing so violates design principles and may break stuff

Comment: but using your suggestion. CFoo won't return the Name property when using ToString()... at some point you'll need to prevent the call to the base implementation and return the Name Property. where is it made?

Comment: @MichaelThePotato What you want is to have some means of doing multiple inheritance. Which give rise to so much chances of error and for which purpose C# specifically designed to do away with by only allowing inheritance to 1 class. What you want or am trying to propose is not good design philosophy

Comment: I'm not suggesting Multiple inheritance because it cant be done, how did you get that impression? My sample doesn't suggest it

Comment: @MichaelThePotato My apologies, I should be answering stackoverflow after several hours of work. I am updating my answer now

Comment: @wpfnoop I have updated the answer, I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: @MichaelThePotato Shoudn't*

Comment: Problem is, that now you've created a coupling between the IName and CBar. you can inherit from CBar and have no effect on your implementation. Implementing a certain interface shouldn't alter the way another inheritance operates. why not just have a class that implements IName and override ToString()? i find that this solution breaks abstraction and causes unneeded coupling.

Comment: @MichaelThePotato for any program to work, there must be some form of coupling. That is true. So what is safe coupling? If a coupling is 1 direction, then it is considered safe. Meaning that one thing can affect another but not the other way round. Why is it safe? Because there would be no issue of stability which can only arise as a result of feedback loop, in other words coupling in 2 directions. Therefore I postulate that my proposed solution is a safe one

Anyway based on what OP asked, this is probably the only way. Other than implementing a proxy, or using some form of AOP